# Customer confusion with jargon

Tags: usability-testing, wording

I am working with customers in an app that helps them visualize where their products are in the order management process. Recently with some testing I discovered that the users were confused by the status stage titled "Fill Rate". When explored further with users a pattern emerged where I found out that the terms "fill rate" didn't mean anything to them.

I expanded on the issue with users and unfortunately didn't come up with a clear verbiage to properly communicate what this stage is.

Are there any online tools that you'd recommend for surveying additional results?

Comment: Do you have access to a competitive analysis? It may be that some of your competitors have some terms that have high adoption in your domain.

Comment: I don't have an answer for the question as asked in the last sentence and I obviously don't have the details of your scenario, but if for example fill rate is meaning the part of the order that can be immediately fulfilled, then that might be labelled 'available from stock' while the remaining amount might be 'on back order'. Is this even the right area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://english.stackexchange.com/ is a good place to ask what a more common alternative is for your complex words.